# Converting a "boolean" string to an array in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, octave

I need to convert a string of boolean indices into an array which would look like this:

```
convert('11001') = [1 2 5]
convert('0000') = []
convert('001') = [3]
```

I don't control the function which produces the string.

Any ideas to do this in an elegant way? I already did it whith a loop but it looks wrong somehow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
function y = convert(s)
y = find(s == '1');
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a variation that converts each character to a number.

```
function y = convert(s)
y = find(str2num(s')')
```